# How to add oAuth profile for SOAP testing

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, soapui

I am able to find option to add oAuth profile for providing token to SOAP authentication. I tried both open source and Pro versions. In your documentation, it is asking to add oAuth profile as mentioned here but there is no such option.

https://www.soapui.org/oauth2/oauth2-authorization/

I don't see any option to add oAuth in my latest version of SoapUI open source. Here is the screenshot of my desktop program.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.